# /lib/modules/*/build point to non existing files

Tags: linux

I have a CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core).

I want to build some kernel code for currently running kernel.

My uname -r says `3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`, but ls -l /usr/src/kernels/
shows only `3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64`. Why do I have sources of not current kernel on my filesystem(vanilla fresh provisioned Digitalocean box)?

Why does yum install kernel-devel does not install headers for currently running kernel?

Comment: The headers are probably same. Why is that a problem?

Comment: `/usr/src/kernels` contains kernel **sources**, which may be built manually (at that place, or after copiing to another location). For able to build modules for kernel, you need to have `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build`  . Where this directory points to?

Comment: @Tsyvarev To /usr/src/kernels of not running kernel version

Comment: Looks like something broken with you packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uname` is a system call to the kernel to get information. It's telling you what's running on that machine. What's physically present on the hard drive can be anything that anyone has installed. Someone may have downloaded the wrong package or you may have multiple kernels installed etc. But, the one that's running is what `uname` is telling you.